# Rendering non-ascii characters from R markdown (Rmd) to both HTML and PDF

Tags: r-markdown, markdown

I'm writing a R markdown document that I wish to be able to render as HTML and as PDF.  It includes some special characters, for instance λ, which I wish to appear in plain text (as it does here).

Typing `&lambda;` or simply pasting `λ` into the markdown works in HTML, but is rendered invisible in the PDF. `$\lambda$` looks good in the PDF, but is rendered unpredictably in HTML, either in a separate font with a different line height or as an image that cannot be copied as text.

There are a number of cases where I wish to include symbols, so I'd rather avoid a complicated if-else statement predicated on the output format.

Is there a simple way to consistently render special characters in the document's default font, regardless of output format?